# Wrong xml format when converting csv file C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

** have a problem when I convert csv-xml with my xml application, it does not read me the characters fine, for example: csv:12" = xml:"12"", csv: B&W=xml:B&w. it is attached to my code, thank you all**

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"H:\EPGVividTVAugust2017.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
        int id = 1;

        var doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\text.csv");

    var xml = new XElement("TopElement",
       lines.Select(line => new XElement("Item",
          line.Split(';')
              .Select((column, index) => new XElement("Column" + index, column)))));

    xml.Save(@"C:\xmlout.xml");
```

XML escape characters

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Many XML issues are caused by string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I put it in my code?

Comment: I know I'm risking a ban here, but it's questions like the comment above me from OP that make me think that this whole website is pretty much pointless nowadays.